# How to push absolute positioned full width image down

Tags: jquery, css, html, background-image

I am trying to make a similar effect as Voets Design has done with their full width image being pushed down by the navigation.

See here: http://www.voetsdesign.com/

So far the navigation and image is looking good; the only problem is that the image isn't being pushed down since it is `position: absolute.

The mark-up:

```
<nav class="clearfix">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How-to</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" id="btn">click</a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="image"></div>
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uvxb53z8/1/

Hope someone has a solution.

Comment: you can surely try inspect element on the website? :/

Comment: I have done that, but it seems like they have the image in a absolute positioned wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main problems that prevented your example from working:

`nav` had a `position: absolute` applied to it (two times, also in a media query). This way it'll never affect layout of other elements as it's been taken out of document flow. You need `relative`for that. You'd see on http://www.voetsdesign.com/ that `.project-panel-header` (the element that is pushing down the image) also has `position: relative` set.

Apart from that, `nav` also had a fixed height (40px). It probably would never push down your image anyway because of that, no matter how high its content might be.

```js
$(function() {
    var btn        = $('#btn');
        menu       = $('nav ul');
        menuHeight = menu.height();
    
    $(btn).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    });
    
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
/* Clearfix */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* Basic Styles */
html {
 height: 1500px;
}

body {
 background-color: #ece8e5;
 margin: 0;
}


/******** NAVIGATION ********/
nav {
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 11pt;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 9;
 display:block;
}

.nav-wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 background-color: #455868;
}

.logo {
 width: 150px;
 height: 40px;
 background: #0CC;
 position: absolute;
}

nav ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
}
nav li {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
}
nav a {
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;
}
nav li a {
 border-right: 1px solid #576979;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
nav li:last-child a {
 border-right: 0;
}
nav a:hover, nav a:active {
 background-color: transparent;
}
nav a#btn {
 display: none;
}



/******** FULLSCREEN BCK ********/

.image {
background-image: url(http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2014/06/wallpaper_51.jpg);
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 background-color: #2b6c72;
}

/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
 nav {
  border-bottom: 0;
  }

 nav ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:300px
 }
 nav a#btn {
  display: block;
  background-color:#000;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height:40px
 }
 nav a#btn:after {
  content:"";
  background: url('nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 10px;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="clearfix">
     <div class="nav-wrapper">
  <ul class="clearfix">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">How-to</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" id="btn">click</a>
        </div>
 </nav>
    
    <div class="image"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maryisdead/rkapkoLu/)

Comment: YES!!!! this is really great!
Thanks a lot, i have been trying to get this working for a few hours now

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

one solution, just to help out a little (and I'm a little bit busy myself atm):

CSS:

```
.image.toggled{
    top: 300px;
}
```

jQ:

```
$(btn).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
    $('.image').toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uvxb53z8/2/

Second solution would be to wrap the content with the element that drops down.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't go for a solution where you animate with javascript. Just add a class to the container and give the container an overflow: hidden;

Then you can animate the image's bottom property with a negative margin and the navigation's height property, assuming the navigation also has a hidden overflow.